# Swifkey Keyboard doesn't react to backspace key in Gluon Project

Tags: gluon-mobile, swift-keyboard

Since the latest update to Swiftkey Keyboard, the backspace key event is not properly recognized / fired.

An eventfilter added to the input node showed that you have to hit backspace several times, until the corresponding key event gets fired. 
This effect only occurs when you try to delete letters. Deleting numbers is working fine.

(Android version 7.0)

Comment: Have you tried doing a long press? It seems like it has some inertia to get started. After that it works fine, like there is something preventing it from working (Swiftkey software I mean).

Comment: Yes a long press is working. Strangely enough this behaviour occurs only in Gluon Projects